# Homothety and rotation and fixed point in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem concerning a comparison of real and complex Analysis on a precise question.

In Analysis we know the definition of a so called contraction mapping which implies the existance of one fixed point, f(x)=x. In the contraction mapping we have: d(f(x),f(y))< k d(x,y), for k positive and <1.
When dealing with the homotheties and rotations on C, one claims that given f(z)=Az+B, if A is different 1, then f is a homothety and rotation ( otherwise it would be a translation ). If the contraction theorem can be applied on C then it would follow that for A<1 you can find a fixed point and thus find the centre of the homethety and rotation depending on B. But since the transformation f(z) can be a homothety and rotation only if A is different 1, it is thus including values of A >1.
My question is:

Is it possible in the case A > 1 to apply the fixed Point theorem even though the condition of the contraction mapping is not realised any more ?

When one writes A>1 is it meant A is complex and thus it is the module of A which is meant ?

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply te fixed point theorem, but you can find the unique fixed point solving the equation $A\,z+B=z$ when $A\ne1$.

$A>1$ indeed should mean that $A$ is real. $f$ is then a dilation.

Comment: Thanks. Is it the same for A <1, A real or this time is it meant the module of A ? Is there a mathematical reference which allows to use the fixed point theorem similar to the contraction theorem in real Analysis ?